# Arduino code - Problem converting non ASCII values in tanks back to an HTML page

Tags: html, string, arduino, char, ascii

Simply put, when I type in an HTML field "test@essai", I get "test%40essai". @ is not converted correctly in my receiving channel.

So I’m looking for a function that would replace character by character, which is in the final string, since it is OK. Or another way to do it further upstream. while works is ok.

My simplified code:

```
String requestBody;

while(client.available()){
   requestBody += (char)client.read();
}

if(requestBody.length()){
   //This is where I would like to convert.
   Serial.println(requestBody);
}
```

If you can help me a little

Comment: What is your request header setting for `Content-Type`?

Comment: what Arduino do you have? different platforms have different built-in support

Answer (score 0):

On the question of the "content-type", see the attached code. This idea had crossed me, and without major change. So exclusion of the content-type.

```
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-type:text/html");
client.println();

client.println("<!doctype html>");
client.println("<html>");
client.println("<head>");
client.println("<meta charset='utf-8'>");
client.println("<title>Test APSAE</title>");
```

Compared to the platform, I am on ESP32, with the Arduino header to simplify. The problem might be different in a different language, though?